# How to get an event to fire using Google Tag Manager for the wordpress audio player?

Tags: events, audio, google-analytics

I am trying to track when people listen to audio I have embeded on a wordpress site via the wordpress [audio] player.  I looked at the source code and inspect element of the play button and there is no class or id.

Does anyone know how to get an event to fire when people click the play button using Google Tag Manager?